# Create Azure web site with Django and SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, visual-studio, azure

I need connect my Django website to Azure SQL database.I use visual studio. And Python 2.7 for 64 bit.

I use this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql/ for create database config

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'xxx',
            'USER': 'xxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
            'HOST': 'xxx.database.windows.net',
            'PORT': '1433',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
                'MARS_Connection': 'True',
            }
        }
}
```

I installed pips: pyodbc and django-pyodbc-azure - I think that them for 32 bit.

If I run python manage.py syncdb from console - > error:

```
django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available databace backend.
No module named sql_server.pyodbc.base
```

If I run python-> Django Sync db from visual studio -> error:

```
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
The Python REPL process has exited
```

1. I don't understand if I can use pyodbc and django-pyodbc-azure for Python 64 bit and it is right for Azure?
2. May be it is another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the latest python 2.7 64 bits version from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.amd64.msi, and leveraged it to create a virtual env in Visual Studio, install modules from `requirements.txt`, configured database info the same as you. 
[image]

Then clicked `sync db`, but I did occur your issue, it worked fine on my side.

You can try to leverage virtual env as the step 3 and step 4 mention on the post https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql/#create-the-project.

And here are the python modules with version in used:

`Django==1.8.4
pyodbc==3.0.10
django-pyodbc-azure==1.8.3.0`

Comment: Thank you. I created new project and it is work right.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sql_server is under Python_xx\Lib\site-packages\ or in the environment PATH or PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can, but if your Python is x86_64 version, then your packages pyodbc and django-pyodbc-azure need to be build for this 64 bits version, check this first if you install the packages from VS or directly from shell/powershell. Check your `$PYTHONPATH`
2. I assume that you are using Django 1.9, syncdb was deprecated from Django 1.7 and don't work with Django 1.9, change your `syncdb` commands with `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` check:

   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/